# Why the container turns vertically when I use future builder?

Tags: flutter, api, dart

[The container without using API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmQxE.jpg)

[The container with using API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoY4D.jpg)

When I use `Axis.horizontal`, it disappears.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: We can't help much without seeing code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.